# Is there any way I can set timezone in laravel 4 database.php configuration file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way I can set timezone in laravel 4 database.php configuration file (like `'timezone' => 'UTC'`)? I'm using mysql date, now and other functions which is giving me two separate time for production and development.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to app->config->app.php in your laravel directory.  On line 43 you can alter the default timezone to whatever you need.

Laravel 4 default:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Your timezone:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
```

This change will then carry over to your database migrations.  Also, if you need to set different timezones based on environment settings, simply add a directory in app->config directory that corresponds to the environment name you specified (ie - "production").  Place a duplicate of "app.php" into your newly created directory and alter the timezone setting on line 43 accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Add 'timezone'  => '+05:30' within 'mysql' in your config->database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        .....
        .....
        .....
        'timezone'  => '+05:30'
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the following at the top of **database.php**, before return array:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

If you want to New York:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
```

And so on. I have tested it and works fine to me.

Comment: Sorry didn't worked for me I had to execute DB::statement("SET time_zone='+0:00';"); before every query.

Answer (score 2):

None of currently available answers helped me, so I came up with that solution:

```
'mysql' => array(
    ...
    'options' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET time_zone = "+00:00"',
    ],
),
```

`'options'` should be added to `mysql` connection data (app/config/database.php).