# Lumen date timezone from database

Tags: php, mysql, lumen

I change my timezone from `UTC` to `Europe/Paris` in my env file.

When I create a `DateTime`, the time is correct (from Paris).

```
$now = new \DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // correct
```

Now, in my databse (MySQL) I have a Timestamp field and I get time -1h :

```
// database value = 2022-01-31 13:35:42
$expired = new \DateTime($this->expired_at);
echo $expired->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // show 2022-01-31 12:35:42
```

Why date get from database look like in UTC instead my new timezone ?

In my PHP project I do :

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+01:00';
SELECT @@global.time_zone, now();
```

When Paris time is 14:00 in PHP for the last query I get :

```
@@global.time_zone => +01:00 
now() => 13:00 // instead of 14:00
```

Comment: In order to avoid total chaos, datetime's in the database are always stored as UTC.

Comment: Good to know, but why when I have 13:35 in db I didn't get 14:35 in Paris timezone ? (Paris is UTC+1)

Comment: data item , **once stored in a db table** , will be static (unless you (or your system) update it) . So after you retrieve it, you need to use programming to change the presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL timezone is separated from PHP timezone. They are two different applications. To set MySQL timezone run this MySQL query in your PHP code:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+01:00';
```

To make sure that works true run this query:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, now();
```

**Edit based on comments**

As told in the comments Laravel framework is used. So the following post is suggested:
[Is there any way I can set timezone in laravel 4 database.php configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493472/is-there-any-way-i-can-set-timezone-in-laravel-4-database-php-configuration-file)

> Go to app->config->app.php in your Laravel directory. On line 43 you can >alter the default timezone to whatever you need.

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

Comment: I get +1:00 with the correct current time (14h) but in PHP I get 13h

Comment: Did you run `SELECT @@global.time_zone, now();` in your PHP code after connecting to the database? Which PHP library do you use for connecting to database?

Comment: I'm with Lumen (Laravel), it use PDO

Comment: You're including this line `$pdoObject->exec("SET @@global.time_zone = '+01:00';");` in your code and nothing changed? Maybe there is no problem in your SQL and should look at your PHP code. Could you include the PHP part in your question or in the comments?

Comment: Ok, sorry I begin with web development.. When I execute your query I have this result `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [@@global.time_zone] => +01:00 [now()] => 2022-01-05 13:22:08 ) )` that's incorrect because now is 14:22 in Paris

Comment: question updated

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493472/is-there-any-way-i-can-set-timezone-in-laravel-4-database-php-configuration-file. I'm not good at Laravel farmwork.

Comment: Perfect! they say to edit database.php but I edit the env file. I have set the timezone for project but I can add a const to set timezone for database too `DB_TIMEZONE=+01:00`